# Can't echo out something after a MySqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Today, I have a question regarding PHP.

I know to be fact based on my setup that this function is being called. However, only the first requested 'echo' is being displayed (I used "cats", long story...).

I know that a lot of times this is something simple like a missed end quote, but my PHP doesn't throw me any errors. Anyting I'm doing wrong? I can't get anything after my code.

Before I do this:

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'VV_root') or die("There was an error connecting; " . mysqli_connect_error);
```

Then this is my function.

```
function knock_on() {
echo("cats");
// It is asssumed that from here, all information is to be kept as secure as possible in the transactions
// Get all the ingredients
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// Now, we have all the ingredients
// Mix password !IMPORTANT!

// Now, run the query to see if we get any matches.
$query = $connection->query("select * from user where username = " . $username . " & password = " . $password) or die("Something went wrong");
echo("cats2");
}
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that you're not escaping your query values.

Comment: probably your query may have problem... It should be select * from user where username = '" . $username . "' & password = '" . $password."'"

Comment: place connection code inside formula

Answer (score 2):

You are running into scope issues. The `$connection` variable is not available inside your  `knock_on()` function. Pass the `$connection` as a parameter to your function definition.

Like this..

`function knock_on($connection) { //Forget the global keyword thing.`

Comment: What do you mean by that? I get what you're talking about, but shouldn't it be global? If not, how do I make it Global and why is it effecting it?

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to your function.

Comment: @ilarsona Add a simple `if($connection){ // your code } else { echo 'Connection is null!'; }` and you'll see what the issue is...

Comment: It's not necessary to set it global, overgive it through a parameter.
If you want to know it [Variable Scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: @TiesonT. That's what it is... but how do I get what exactly is wrong with it? My password is correct, the hostname is correct, and the database exists.

Comment: With the check of Tieson, you could see if the connection was successful.

Comment: Took me a while but the connection was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all turn on error displaying and then you have an error in your query:

```
$query = $connection->query("select * from user where username = " . $username . " & password = " . $password) or die("Something went wrong");
```

Here you need to use `AND` operator not an `&` as you did:

```
 username = " . $username . " AND password = " . $password
```

Abnd the second : `$connection` variable is not available inside your `knock_on()` function as 
Shankar Damodaran mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Note this code is not tested.

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'VV_root') or die("There was an error connecting; " . mysqli_connect_error);

function knock_on() {
   global $connection;
echo("cats");
// It is asssumed that from here, all information is to be kept as secure as possible in the transactions
// Get all the ingredients
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// Now, we have all the ingredients
// Mix password !IMPORTANT!

// Now, run the query to see if we get any matches.
$query = $connection->query("select * from user where username = " . $username . " & password = " . $password) or die("Something went wrong");
if($query) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were several things that I had to fix, so here's my new working code

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "VV_root");
```

The actual function:

```
function knock_on() {
echo("cats");
// It is asssumed that from here, all information is to be kept as secure as possible in the transactions
// Get all the ingredients
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// Now, we have all the ingredients
// Mix password !IMPORTANT!

// Now, run the query to see if we get any matches.
if ($connection) {
$query = $connection->query("select * from user where username = '" . $username . "' and password = '" . $password . "'") or die("Something went wrong");
}
else {
echo($mysqli->connect_error);
}
echo("cats2");

}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you should not be directly injecting query values into your query string. Look into prepared statements at some point: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and `filter_var()`: http://us3.php.net/filter_var

Comment: Thanks. This is just the groundwork... I'm doing all the fancy stuff later.